# как остановить сервер запущенный через maven java

Tags: java, spring, maven

возможно тупой вопрос но все таки.
запустил приложение (по этому [туториалу](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)) через maven

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

теперь не могу понять как остановить, запуска через git bash ОП Windows10

Comment: Комбинацией клавиш Ctrl+C

Comment: это первое что я сделал, не остановился

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Когда я случайно запускаю в фоне какие-то программы, самый простой способ найти Java в диспетчере задач и завершить этот процесс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте так: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown

Comment: Я имел ввиду любое java приложение, которое запускается в фоне, конечно, у spring'а есть свои методы закрытия, но это самый простой способ по моему мнению